# How to get the latest version of an app programmatically?

Tags: android, version, getlatest

I want to check programmatically if my app's version is the latest existing. With iOS, I would use this HTTP request :

> http://itunes.apple.com/fr/lookup?bundleId=com.EC.EmploiCollectivites

Then, parse the JSON stream to get the version.

How can I do this (and is there a way) for Android ? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do this (and is there a way) for Android ?

Store some JSON on your own server with the latest version information, then download that JSON.

Comment: Ok that's a good idea, I already thought of this. But is there a way to do it with something existing, like this URL for iOS apps?

Comment: @Rob: Nothing that is documented and supported.

Comment: Ok so I'm gonna do that. Thanks again.